# Eigenvalues of a circulant matrix with an updated term

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, toeplitz-matrices, circulant-matrices

$$ \begin{Bmatrix} 
    a & b & 0 &\dots & 0 & c \\ 
    c & 0 & b &\dots & 0 & 0 \\ 
    0 & c & \ddots &\ddots & 0 & 0 \\ 
    \vdots & 0 & \ddots &\ddots & b & 0 \\ 
    \vdots & 0 & \ddots &\ddots & 0 & b \\ 
    b & 0 & \dots &0 & c & 0 \\ 
    \end{Bmatrix} $$

where $b, c \in \Bbb R$ and $b\ne c$. I would like to solve the eigenvalues of this $n \times n$ matrix, and see the impact of $a$ on its eigenvalues. This circulant matrix models a physical problem with BCs, finding an analytical solution allows to understand the asymptotic cases, for instance,

- $a=0$, then the eigenvalues are supposed to be complex (and are [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix))
- $a \to \inf$ and purely imaginary, the eigenvalues should be real.

I tried already some methods, for instance to do it iteratively, but unfortunately this wasn't helpful.

Comment: Computing with maple (up to order 30), shows that the determinant does not change if $n$ is even, and changes if $n$ is odd. In the case of odd $n$, the difference between the original determinant and the determinant with the $a$ is (-1)^{(n-1)}a(bc)^{(n-1)/2}$.

Comment: Thanks for your proposal, but I'm looking for the eigenvalues.

I found a way to write the characteristic polynomial, which will be the sum of the characteristic polynomial, p=det(H-I\lambda)+a*det(HM_{11} -I\lambda)), where H is the this previous matrix without the diagonal term, and HM_{11} the first minor matrix of H, which is equal to a Toeplitz matrix of size N-1